# How do I iterate through nested vectors?

Tags: c++, list, vector, tuples, std

I have a rather complex ordered internal Grammar representation of my productions consisting of typed std libarary classes:

```
class Grammar {
    std::tuple<int, NonTerminal, std::vector<std::vector<Symbol>>> productions;
}
```

Now I would like to create LR0-Items from this representation.

From inner to outer:

- `std::vector<Symbol>` represents a rule
- `std::vector<std::vector<Symbol>>` represents an alternative rule of the production.
- `NonTerminal, std::vector<std::vector<Symbol>>>` represents the lhs of the production
- `std::tuple<int, NonTerminal, std::vector<std::vector<Symbol>>>` represents the order of the productions.

Question: How do I iterate through the productions? I am new to c++. As far as I know the way is through an `::iterator`. But then, **how do I address one nested datatype** to build an iterator from it?

Thanks

EDIT:

Instead of `std::tuple` I think it's yet better to have the definition consist of two times a `std::pair` :

```
std::pair<int, std::pair<NonTerminal, std::vector<std::vector<Symbol>>> productions;
```

I try to adopt the answer of user `idclev 463035818`

```
for( const &auto production : productions.back) {
  for( const &auto alternatives : production.back) {
    for( const &auto rule : alternatives) {
     // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Correct ?

Comment: Is it important to the question that you try to build your own representation of a grammar?

Comment: How look like your LR0-item?

Comment: Not necessary simple to create an iterator from that, but you can simply iterate over the nested container.

Comment: Do you have any examples in your C++ textbook that you can model off, as an example?

Comment: My c++ Textbooks are about 15 years old and I would have to search a dozen cardboard boxes to find them. : ( Addressing nested containers (is this way of speaking correct?) seems to be not a trivial problem in C++ ... At least for (re) beginners like me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate a vector whose elements are of type `T` you can use a range based for loop:

```
std::vector<T> vect;
for (const auto& element : vect) {
    // element is a const reference to elements of vect
    // put code here
}
```

Now, if `T` is again a vector, you just replace `//put code here` with your code to iterate that vector `element`.

---

Nesting containers is not as complicated as you might expect. It does not require special treatment. If you know how to iterate one vector and get a reference to its elements, then you already do know how to iterate those elements in case they are vectors.

---

So lets say you have a `std::vector<std::vector<Symbol>>>` (I'll skip the tuple, because I suppose you don't want to "iterate" it, but just pick the 3rd element from it).

```
std::vector<std::vector<Symbol>>> vect_vect;

for (const auto& vect : vect_vect) {
    // here vect is a const reference to std::vector<Symbol>
    for (const auto& symbol : vect) {
       // here symbol is a const reference to a Symbol
       // put your code here
       // eg assuming Symbol has a member get_bar
       auto foo = symbol.get_bar();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I address the further elements of the Container with `elements`.<whatever> ?

Comment: @vonspotz if `T` is a `foo` and `foo` has a member `bar` then `element.bar` refers to that member

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the problem is that, as you can see above, the containers are of different types and have no name-handle ! :( Only type.

Comment: @vonspotz sorry, but then you didnt understand my answer. The message I wanted to get across is: It does not matter what is the type of the elements. Iterating them always works the same. With `auto` you can use exact same code, no matter what `T` actually is. What does it mean "have no name-handle"? I don't understand. If you have problems with errors in code you have written then you need to show that code. But please consider that this question already has an answer, so you shouldn't change the question to ask for something else, better open a new one

Comment: Maybe I should try to somehow model the hierarchy via inheritance and either derive some classes from `vector<T>` or make them members ?

Comment: No I don't doubt your answer was correct. I just dont know which identifier would reference the next inner container(?). You said `element.bar`. Maybe you could be so nice to elaborate based on the example I gave of my "productions" object ? Thank you VERY much !

Wait. Let me guess. I can give the next inner container (correct terminology?) *any* name in the `range based loop` ?

Comment: @vonspotz I am afraid that there is a misunderstanding somewhere (not necessarily on your side). I added a more detailed example